# How to render nested messages using content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-tag

I want to render nested ul li list using content_tag like

```
<ul>   <li>
    <div>Message1</div>    </li>    <li>
     <div>Message 2</div>
    </li> </ul>
```

I have helper method like this

```
def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
      content_tag :ul do
        content_tag :li do
          render(message) + nested_messages(sub_messages)
        end
      end 
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

I didn't get the nested list. My output looks like this

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Message 1</div>
   </li>
</ul> 
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Message 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where I am doing wrong? How to get the correct nested list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest the `messages.map` block inside the `ul` content tag block:

```
def nested_messages(messages)
  content_tag :ul do
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
      content_tag :li do
        render(message) + nested_messages(sub_messages)
      end
    end.join
  end.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting undefined method `join' for "<ul></ul>"

Comment: Sorry updated my answer, the `join` should be on the inner `messages.map` block.